# Fail to send push notification

Tags: azure, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to follow the [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn265921.aspx), to send out push notification:

```
var hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString("Endpoint=sb://xxx-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature;SharedAccessKey=xxx=", "xxxapp");
                hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync("{ \"data\" : {\"msg\":\"Hello from Windows Azure!\"}}", "xxxapp");
            }
```

But I get no response? SendGcmNativeNotification is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SendGcmNativeNotification is marked as internal in Service Bus SDK 2.1.
As for your issue, SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync() doesn't return actual result, it returns a task. The following is an example how you would consume it using c# 5 syntax:

```
private static async Task<NotificationOutcomeState> CallNotificationHub()
{
    var hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(
                "<your connection string with full access>",
                "<your notification hub name>");
    var outcome = await hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(
                        "{ \"data\" : {\"msg\":\"Hello from Windows Azure!\"}}");
    return outcome.State;
}

CallNotificationHub().Wait();
```